# How to scrape data using xpath contains?

Tags: xpath

How can i exclude element to be scraped using contains with OR my current xpath that i use is not working.
//div/li[contains(text(), 'Night') OR contains(text(), 'Big')

Comment: you should use `not` operator to exclude. see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete @Sergii Dmytrenko's answer, use also a lowercase `or` operator.

```
//div/li[contains(text(), 'Night') or contains(text(), 'Big')]
```

The preceding XPath will output `li` elements containing the text "Night" or "Big" (case sensitive).

In order to exclude elements, you can use the `not` operator as previoulsy described.

Side note : using `!=` (not equal) with `and` operator is also possible to exclude elements :

```
//div/li[text()!='Night' and text()!='Big']
```

This will exclude elements which strictly contain (no more text) "Night" or "Big".

---

**EDIT** : Assuming you have :

```
<div>
  <h2>Night of the living dead</h2>
  <h2>Big fish</h2>
  <h2>Save the last dance</h2>
  <h2>Tomorrow never die</h2>
  <h2>Australia nuclear war</h2>
</div>
```

To select elements which don't contain "Night","Big", or "Australia", you have two options :

Using `or` operators inside a `not` condition :

```
//div/h2[not(contains(text(),'Night') or contains(text(),'Big') or contains(text(),'Australia'))]
```

Using multiple `not` with and operators :

```
//div/h2[not(contains(text(),'Night')) and not(contains(text(),'Big')) and not(contains(text(),'Australia'))]
```

Output : 2 nodes :

```
Save the last dance
Tomorrow never die
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the help but still gives me a #N/A for an answer.

Comment: //div/h2[not(contains(text(),'Night')) or not(contains(text(),'Big')) OR not(contains(text(),'Australia'))] still #N/A for an answer

Comment: I've updated my answer. Since you're using multiple `not`, you have to use `and` operator, not `or`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you E. Wiest

Comment: Glad to help.  Please accept the best answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression (if corrected the typos: `li[contains(text(), 'Night') or contains(text(), 'Big')]`) will return `li` elements having the text "Night" or "Big".

to exclude these the correct expression should be

```
//div/li[not(contains(text(), 'Night') or contains(text(), 'Big'))]
```

or you may try

```
//div/li[not(contains(text(), 'Night')) and not(contains(text(), 'Big'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your xpath should end with ']', currently it is invalid one.
2. If you would like to exclude 'Night' and 'Big' you may try this:

   //div/li[not(contains(text(), 'Night') OR contains(text(), 'Big'))]